# MVC5 DataBaseFirst Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Can i use Database First without using .edmx or designer approach?
I do have a Model, DbContext class and in web.config i do have my connection string as:

```
 <add name="TestEntities"      connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Prakash_Test;user id=SA;password=P;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Database first approach means that you can create models(classes) based on existing database or you can create new SQL database project create table, publish it on SQL server. Then import models.(classes).
[Getting started with database first approach](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)

Comment: I don't want to use designer approach or codeFirst approach

Comment: I want go for Databasefirst approach but other than designer approach

Comment: Are you going to use entity framework for creating data layer?